# JSF update managed bean with ServletContext listener for testing

Tags: jsf, mocking

In a JSF 2.2 application, I want to build a war file for testing with Selenium. In that webtest.war, I want to replace a central class, called the NodeCache, with a mock version, called the WebtestNodeCache, to keep the database and other external dependencies out of the tests.

NodeCache is a managed bean:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(name = NodeCache.INSTANCE)
@javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped
public class NodeCache {
    public static final String INSTANE = "nodecache";
    // ...
}
```

To sneak in WebtestNodeCache, I use a ServletContextListener like this:

```
public class WebtestContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
     @Override
     public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
         WebtestNodeCache nodeCache = new WebtestNodeCache();
         ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
         context.setAttribute(NodeCache.INSTANCE, nodeCache);
     }

     @Override
     public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}
}
```

In normal builds, WebtestContextListener and WebtestNodeCache are excluded from the war file, in test builds, they are included.

This seems to work: when I log in, I get dummy nodes from the WebtestNodeCache.

Is this a reliable way to replace a bean in application context or did I just get lucky?

Is there a better way to sneak in test dummies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using both an `@ManagedBean` annotation and a Listener to replace the object did not work. The code was always using the unmocked production code managed bean.

Defining a new `@ManagedBean` with the same name is an error and prevents deployment.

I ended up with this:

- Put the `@ManagedBean` annotation with the same name on both the real bean and its mock.
- When building, only include the mocks when building the webtest.war, but not in the regular build.
- When building, have the build script (Gradle in my case) copy and filter the sources, looking for a special comment behind the `@ManagedBean` declaration in the production code and taking out these lines to remove the `@ManagedBean` declaration on the production code so that only the ones in the mock remains.

So the original NodeCache looks like this now:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(name = NodeCache.INSTANCE) // webtest:remove
@javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped // webtest:remove
public class NodeCache {
    public static final String INSTANE = "nodecache";
    // ...
}
```

and the mocked version has the same annotations, just without the comment:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(name = NodeCache.INSTANCE)
@javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped
public class WebtestNodeCache extends NodeCache {
    // ...
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the Gradle build script:

```
boolean isWebtest = false
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    isWebtest = taskGraph.hasTask(compileWebtestWarJava);
}

task copySrc(type: Copy) {
    from "src"
    into "${buildDir}/src"
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        // Always execute this task so that resources do or don't get filtered
        // when switching between normal war file and webtests.
        false
    }
    filter { String line ->
        isWebtest && line.contains("webtest:remove") ? null : line;
    }
}
```

This solves the problem for me. Hope someone else finds it useful.